# how to set different colors on each pie chart with data from ajax

Tags: javascript, pie-chart, amcharts

how to set different colors on each pie chart with data from ajax with if condition?

this is my piechart js

```
var data_kendala = [];

$.each(data.data8, function(key, val){
  data_kendala.push({
    "country": val.CONTRAINTS_NAME,
    "visits": val.TOTAL_KENDALA,
    "color": "#fd0000"
  });
});
```

I want to set each color on different chart, for example if `CONTRAINTS_NAME = 1` then green color, if `CONTRAINTS_NAME = 2` then blue and etc.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to set your color inside the `each` according to your specific conditions. Or I missed a point.

```
$.each(data.data8, function(key, val){
  var color;

  // set your color according to conditions
  // Like: color = CONTRAINTS_NAME === 1 ? 'green' : 'blue';

  data_kendala.push({
    "country": val.CONTRAINTS_NAME,
    "visits": val.TOTAL_KENDALA,
    "color": color
  });
});
```

Comment: I think yes, the answer in the current context is valid, but what happens when the data set increases to say 500 items?

Comment: The user might need to create dynamic colors instead.

Comment: I agree, for an infinity of constraints, he should create dynamic colours.

Comment: i have to try var color;color = CONTRAINTS_NAME === "Lahan" ? 'green' : 'blue'; but i got error CONTRAINTS_NAME is not define

Comment: Yes, try it with `val.CONTRAINTS_NAME === ...`. Come back for any issue.

Comment: the color not different with the other, all off constraints_name is the same color bro